# Cloudfront GoDaddy DNS - SSL Certificate Issues

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl, godaddy, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-acm

I have a CloudFront distribution setup and working correctly. I also have an SSL certificate issued using ACM.

My GoDaddy DNS has a CNAME entry for www which points to the cloudfront distribution

The following URLS work as expected and display the CloudFront distribution...

```
https://www.example.com
http://www.example.com
http://example.com
```

But this one does not..

```
https://example.com
```

It gives me a non-secure page error, looking further into it I can see that is it because the domain is actually the GoDaddy URL shortener shortener.secureserver.net which the SSL certificate does not recognise.

Anyone any idea how I can resolve? Can I create another CNAME entry for @?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can’t CNAME your root domain name, and for that reason you should avoid using or promoting it. However, if you move your DNS to Cloudflare, they have a [workaround for this](https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-cname-flattening-rfc-compliant-cnames-at-a-domains-root/).

Comment: Is moving the DNS to Route53 an option? I am keen to keep as many things under one roof as possible

Comment: Yes, you should be able to use a Route53 alias record. See here for instructions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-cloudfront-distribution.html

Comment: Thanks, reading up on that now. Looks like a good solution